# iPhone app Facebook login permission error

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am getting "An error ocurred with [App Name]. Please try again later" from facebook in native iPhone app.

The step to reproduce this error follows:

1. Login to fb
2. first time works fine
3. Logout from fb
4. Try to login to app
5. Error

Pls help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling then reinstalling? Also there is a known bug in the first 5.0 release of the facebook app which sounds similar to your problem. They have released an updated version.